# model.get_weights() returning array of NaNs after training due to NaN masking

Tags: python, keras

I'm trying to train an LSTM to classify sequences of various lengths. I want to get the weights of this model, so I can use them in stateful version of the model. Before training, the weights are normal. Also, the training seems to run successfully, with a gradually decreasing error. However, when I change the mask value from `-10` to `np.Nan`, `mod.get_weights()` starts returning arrays of `NaN`s and the validation error drops suddenly to a value close to zero. Why is this occurring?

```
from keras import models
from keras.layers import Dense, Masking, LSTM
from keras.optimizers import RMSprop
from keras.losses import categorical_crossentropy
from keras.preprocessing.sequence import pad_sequences

import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt


def gen_noise(noise_len, mag):
    return np.random.uniform(size=noise_len) * mag


def gen_sin(t_val, freq):
    return 2 * np.sin(2 * np.pi * t_val * freq)


def train_rnn(x_train, y_train, max_len, mask, number_of_categories):
    epochs = 3
    batch_size = 100

    # three hidden layers of 256 each
    vec_dims = 1
    hidden_units = 256
    in_shape = (max_len, vec_dims)

    model = models.Sequential()

    model.add(Masking(mask, name="in_layer", input_shape=in_shape,))
    model.add(LSTM(hidden_units, return_sequences=False))
    model.add(Dense(number_of_categories, input_shape=(number_of_categories,),
              activation='softmax', name='output'))

    model.compile(loss=categorical_crossentropy, optimizer=RMSprop())

    model.fit(x_train, y_train, batch_size=batch_size, epochs=epochs,
              validation_split=0.05)

    return model


def gen_sig_cls_pair(freqs, t_stops, num_examples, noise_magnitude, mask, dt=0.01):
    x = []
    y = []

    num_cat = len(freqs)

    max_t = int(np.max(t_stops) / dt)

    for f_i, f in enumerate(freqs):
        for t_stop in t_stops:
            t_range = np.arange(0, t_stop, dt)
            t_len = t_range.size

            for _ in range(num_examples):
                sig = gen_sin(f, t_range) + gen_noise(t_len, noise_magnitude)
                x.append(sig)

                one_hot = np.zeros(num_cat, dtype=np.bool)
                one_hot[f_i] = 1
                y.append(one_hot)

    pad_kwargs = dict(padding='post', maxlen=max_t, value=mask, dtype=np.float32)
    return pad_sequences(x, **pad_kwargs), np.array(y)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    noise_mag = 0.01
    mask_val = -10
    frequencies = (5, 7, 10)
    signal_lengths = (0.8, 0.9, 1)
    dt_val = 0.01

    x_in, y_in = gen_sig_cls_pair(frequencies, signal_lengths, 50, noise_mag, mask_val)
    mod = train_rnn(x_in[:, :, None], y_in, int(np.max(signal_lengths) / dt_val), mask_val, len(frequencies))
```

This persists even if I change the network architecture to `return_sequences=True` and wrap the `Dense` layer with `TimeDistributed`, nor does removing the LSTM layer.

Comment: Why would you want to use NaN as mask value? You don't seem to have NaN in your input anywhere

Comment: @shadi exactly. it's not in my input so I thought it would make a good mask value

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem. In your case I can see it was probably something different but someone might have the same problem and come here from Google. So in my case I was passing sample_weight parameter to fit() method and when the sample weights contained some zeros in it, get_weights() was returning an array with NaNs. When I omitted the samples where sample_weight=0 (they were useless anyway if sample_weight=0), it started to work.

Comment: weights should be initially non zeros, biases may be zeros. However, Keras takes care of that.

Answer (score 0):

`get_weights()` method of `keras.engine.training.Model` instance should retrieve the weights of the model.

This should be a flat list of Numpy arrays, or in other words this should be the list of all weight tensors in the model.

```
mw = model.get_weights()
print(mw)
```

If you got the NaN(s) this has a specific meaning. You are dealing simple with vanishing gradients problem. (In some cases even with Exploding gradients).

I would first try to alter the model to reduce the chances for the vanishing gradients. Try reducing the `hidden_units` first, and normalize your activations.

Even though LSTM are there to solve the problem of vanishing/exploding gradients problem you need to set the right activations from (-1, 1) interval.

### Note this interval is where float points are most precise.

Working with `np.nan` under the masking layer is not a predictable operation since you cannot do comparison with `np.nan`.

Try `print(np.nan==np.nan)` and it will return `False`. This is an old problem with the IEEE 754 standard.

Or it may actually be this is a bug in Tensorflow, based on the IEEE 754 standard weakness.

Comment: Why would changing the mask value change the gradient calculated?

Comment: working with `np.nan` is unpredictable. Try `print(np.nan==np.nan)` it means this masking will not work.

Answer (score 0):

The weights are indeed changing. The unchanging weights are from the edge of the image, and they may have not changed because the edge isn't helpful for classifying digits.
to check select a specific layer and see the result:

```
print(model.layers[70].get_weights()[1])
```

**70 : is the number of the last layer in my case.**