# weights of keras model are nan

Tags: python, keras, deep-learning

I'm using below model for regression purpose; with input of size 2 and output of size 28.

```
from keras.models import Sequential
from keras.layers import Dense
from keras.optimizers import SGD

model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(16, input_dim=2, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(16, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(28, activation='linear'))
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True)
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error',optimizer=sgd)
```

In training all going well, but when I save and reload the model; I'm getting weights as a nan.

```
from keras.models import model_from_json

model_json = model.to_json()
with open('/models/model_ar.json', "w") as json_file:
     json_file.write(model_json)
model.save_weights('/models/model_wt.h5')

json_file = open('/models/model_ar.json', 'r')
loaded_model_json = json_file.read()
json_file.close()
new_model = model_from_json(loaded_model_json)
# load weights into new model
new_model.load_weights('/models/model_wt.h5')
```

getting weights as 'nan'. What is reason to get the all weights as nan

```
    new_model.get_weights()
[array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32),
 array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan], dtype=float32),
 array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan]], dtype=float32),
 array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan], dtype=float32),
 array([[nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan],
        [nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
         nan, nan]], dtype=float32),
 array([nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan, nan,
        nan, nan], dtype=float32)]
```

Comment: is the case same if you use `save` instead of `save_weights`?

Comment: Yes, facing the same issue with save also.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44258458/model-get-weights-returning-array-of-nans-after-training-due-to-nan-masking 
can you please go through the solution to this. Does this solves the problem?

Comment: Does it print `nan` when you `get_weights` after training finishes? It might be becoming `nan`  at training time.

Comment: Yes, I have checked. They are nan at training time. That's why after relaod.

Answer (score 1):

Try

```
sgd = SGD(lr=0.01, decay=1e-6, momentum=0.9, nesterov=True, clipvalue=0.5)
```

from https://www.dlology.com/blog/how-to-deal-with-vanishingexploding-gradients-in-keras/
You can also try `clipnorm=1.` or try one of those parameters with even smaller values.

This limits how much the weights can change in each step of the gradient descent. It worked for me when I had the same problem and I hope it helps!

Answer (score 1):

In my case, there were `NaN` rows in the dataset that I didn't notice. So please check your dataset and values. Check the answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/53641825/1626431)