# Loss: NaN in Keras while performing regression

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras, deep-learning, linear-regression

I am trying to predict a continuous value (using a Neural Network for the first time). I have normalized the input data. I can't figure out why I am getting a `loss: nan` output starting with the first epoch.

I read and tried many suggestions from previous answers to the same question but that none of them helped me.  My training data shape is: `(201917, 64)`. Here's my code:

```
model = Sequential()
model.add(Dense(100, input_dim=X.shape[1], activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))
model.add(Dense(100, activation='relu'))

# Output layer
model.add(Dense(1, activation='linear'))

# Construct the neural network inside of TensorFlow
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam')

# train the model
model.fit(X_train, y_train, epochs=10, batch_size=32,
shuffle=True, verbose=2)
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve. People can usually only help if they can follow and debug.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

These are the steps that you can take to find the cause of your problem:

1. Make sure that your dataset is what it should be:

   - Look for any **nan**/**inf** in your dataset and fix it.
   - Incorrect encoding (convert it to **UTF-8**).
   - Invalid values in your column or rows.
2. Normalize your model using **Dropout**, **BatchNormalization**, **L1**/**L2** **regularization**, change your **batch_size**, or scale your data to other ranges (e.g. **[-1, 1]**).
3. Reduce the size of your network.
4. Change other hyper-parameters (e.g. **optimizer** or **activation function**).

You can check [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37232782/nan-loss-when-training-regression-network) and [this](https://github.com/keras-team/keras/issues/2134) link to get extra help.

Comment: The first item solved my problem. I had `NaN` values in my dataset that I didn't notice. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Sometimes one gets nan loss when the learning rate is too high. One solution could be to lessen it. Replace this code:

```
# Construct the neural network inside of TensorFlow
model.compile(loss='mean_squared_error', optimizer='Adam')
```

with:

```
from keras.optimizers import Adam #maybe put this at the top of your file
opt = Adam(lr=0.0001) #0.001 was the default, so try a smaller one
model.compile(optimizer=opt, loss='mean_squared_error')
```

See if that helps.  I would also try with one hidden layer first and see how it goes.

Comment: adding multiple dense layers for lstm sequential with above parameters give me Nan if nothing else is unchanged. Any advice folks? Do I need multiple dense layers if my output is only one column?

Answer (score 1):

`NaN` in the input data frame. Before getting the data frame values, the `NaN` values should be replaced. Otherwise, it will explode the gradient.

Comment: True that! ```df.isnull().sum()```